# Auto transitions in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do some transitions in css but they all seem to be based off of user interactions.

I can't use Javascript.

But how do I make an element transition from when the page first loads and make it go 3seconds, and then another transition automatically start at 6seconds?

```
#Content img {
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   opacity: 1;
   transition all 3s;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to make it go from 0 opacity to 1 opacity in 3 seconds without hover or click or anything - just all by iteself. How can we do this?

Comment: Use animations instead

Comment: animations are useless for seo. I can't use them.

Comment: I'm unsure I understand what SEO would have to do with it. CSS Animations are the only way to achieve what you desire without javascript: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/ If those are acceptable, let us know and a solution will be posted.

Comment: @ChrisHardie, apologies. I thought he was referring to GIF animations. I've never heard of CSS animations before.

Comment: Thanks for the link and thanks @dc5. CSS animations are what I'm after. :)

Comment: Ooh thanks guys, CSS animations are really cool!